# Strange behavior with getChildFragmentManager in Android 4.3 and less

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I've a problem with getChildFragmentManager method.

I used it to create several nested fragments in viewpager. This Viewpager is in PopupWindow.
In this way, fragments are created and I can see them in UI.
Fragments contain a gridview.

Unfortunately, with android 4.3(API 18) or less, I can't select item of gridview.
In the same time, with android 4.4 (API 19) I can do it!

To intercept item click I used callbacks to Activity, and Activity onAttach method is correct.

I think that problems are caused by getChildFragmentManager, but I'm not sure.

If someone had this problem, can he explain me his solution?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to place EditText's within the GridView? What kinds of controls are within the GridView?

Comment: Gridview contains imageView! I want to click imageview to start some action, but this click is not intercepted!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

With Adroid 4.4 I didn't have problem so I didn't change nothing to my code. In this way, I add a listener in the gridview.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

... // class extends Listener

 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d("EmojiconGridFragment","entered");
    if (mOnEmojiconClickedListener != null) {
        if(DEBUG) Log.d("EmojiconGridFragment","itemClicked");
        mOnEmojiconClickedListener.onEmojiconClicked((Emojicon) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
    }
}
```

With android 4.3 and early, I must add code to handle click item because click isn't intercept with normal listener. So, I get it for each item, like below:

```
//in the adapter class for grid view insert this code
if(!Utils.hasKitKat()) {
        holder.icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Emoicons", " clicked");
                view.setSelected(true);
                mOnEmojiconClickedListener.onEmojiconClicked(emoji);
            }
        });
    }
```

where Utils.HasKitkat() is a method to check if it run in android kitkat or not.

```
public static boolean hasKitKat() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
}
```

I hope this solution is useful for someone.

Comment: I'm happy to help someone! :D

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a very similar problem recently however my scenario was a little different in that I was trying to embed an EditBox within an android ListView (GridView would make no difference).

The problem is that the GridViewItem attempts to gain focus instead of the ImageView so it causes unexpected problems with which control gets focus.

Think of it like this... instead of the ImageView being selected (as you may want) the GridViewItem is getting focus instead and that is what is causing your problem.

I solved this by removing the listview and implementing a vertically orientated LinearView contained inside of a ScrollViewer, I would imagine that you may need to think about doing the same thing...

The alternative to this is to place the code that would usually be handled by the ImageView click inside the ItemClickListener on the grid view and not on each ImageView.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
};
```

That would probably be an easier solution for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I used second way to intercept item click: a listener for the gridview and not for each image view! But, i've this problem!

Comment: If you still have this problem then you will need to post some code so that we can take a better look at what is happening.

Comment: I Solved problem. or better, I circumvented the problem. I used for Android 4.3 single itemclick listener for each item, and for android 4.4 I used a clicklistener for gridview!

Comment: yeah, I'll do it. I now am so busy! I'll do it soon!

Comment: Surely it would take longer to type that comment than accept the answer that someone took time out of their own busy working day to help you with?

Comment: I understand your reply, but I had problems (work and family) so I put my solution when I can do it.